# HTML body in system mail of Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to format the email sent by Drupal via html when I enter a new user. The thing seems to be more difficult than expected, I tried to use the `hook_mail_alter` function, but to no avail. Each time I insert HTML tags these are transformed as in the example below.

How can this be solved? Is it possible to resolve the issue without adding modules ?

```
function importuser_mail_alter(&$message) {
    switch ($message['key']) {
        case 'register_admin_created':
            $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;';
            foreach ($message['body'] as $key => &$body) {
                $body = new Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup($body, []);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

The email in the system is:

```
<strong>Gentile Utente,</strong>

Un amministratore ha creato il tuo profilo utente sul sito DEV. Puoi
autenticarti con un clic su questo collegamento oppure copiando ed incollando
il collegamento nel tuo browser: [...]
```

---

The email received is transformed like this:

```
*Gentile Utente,*

Un amministratore ha creato il tuo profilo utente sul sito DEV. Puoi
autenticarti con un clic su questo collegamento oppure copiando ed incollando
il collegamento nel tuo browser: [...]
```